# div changing the behavior of anchor id links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these following codes, i'm trying to access the website with http://www.mylink.com/index.html#parceiros and the browser shows one div that is so much below my select div #parceiros. I did try to solve this by removing my banner section and the bug goes off. What I need to change to correct this?

PS: navbar is fixed-top

Nav:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-main">
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#servicos">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#info-ejudi">INSTITUCIONAL</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#parceiros">PARCEIROS</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Banner:

```
<div id="slide-banner">
     <div class="item" style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ), url('img/image-banner.jpg') no-repeat">
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#slide-banner .item
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  background-size: cover !important
  background-position: center center
  width: 100%
  height: 80vh
```

Comment: try changing css properties of image in banner, like width and size of banner, image size must be conflicting

Comment: Your link doesn't work. From what I understand, you click on the menu nav item and the page scrolls below of the section you wish to go. Do you have an anchor like `<a name="parceiros"></a>` somewhere in your markup?

Comment: I'm using [http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/] Slick to carousel, with two slides I get this bug, with one don't. =/
No, i don't have another anchor tag with the same name.

Comment: Hey @JoãoVictor - do still need advice on this?

Comment: Thank you for reply @Axel, but I handled it, my script for page-scroll was wrong, and changed the offset solve that.